# What is wrong to initialize an int vector like this: vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}?

Tags: c++, vector

When I initialize a vector in C++ like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::string;
int main() {

  vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  return 0;
}
```

I got this error:

```
prog1.cpp:8:15: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
  vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
              ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Set an option of the compiler to compile the program as a C++11 program.

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializer lists were introduced from C++ 11 onwards, so you'll need to specify that (or a higher) version while compiling (`-std=version`) if your using an older standard for default compilation.